# Creating a cylinder in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, cs6

I have a rectangular shape(*in fact a label*) which is `100cm x 84cm`, now I wanna create a cylinder. PS CS6 has a cylinder preset, when I want to scale that preset cylinder it becomes something that in fact is not a *cylinder*. My question is how can I create a cylinder that I can cover it by my label? How can I create a cylinder from a rectangular shape using PS CS6?

Comment: You'll have to give us a little more detail. How are you creating the layer, what is the exact effect you are trying to achieve, and in what way is your result not a cylinder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Undefined**:  If you are talking about **converting a Bitmap Layer to a 3D Preset** (*Mesh From Preset > Cylinder*), I believe you'll need to **start with an image that is 3:2 (width:height)** so that it will wrap around the cylinder with minimal distortion.

This means that you'll need to adjust your artwork to fit by either adjusting your master or by padding out the canvas with a border.  The bitmap layer you convert will become the cylinder's Cylinder_Material.

**Example**: A 768x512 image/layer which was duplicated twice and all three layers were converted with Mesh From Preset > Cylinder and then merged.  I added and IBL, Camera Focus and Depth of Field, and adjusted the material's properties just a bit, just because:

[image]
[image]

**Note**: I only let it render out a few passes; letting it render longer (or adjusting the Quality in Preferences) would clear up more of the noise in the rendering.

I hope this helps and remember, this is for the Cylinder, not Soda (Can) mesh preset.  Good luck!